# Links (to either a file or www) suddenly unresponsive. "ObjectNotFound" "CommandNotFoundException"?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I'm a newbie when it comes to HTML. I was practicing some basics, including using anchor tags.

It was working just fine. Pulled up the picture perfectly, as with the website.

Suddenly, for no apparent reason, links in general (be it either to a file or a website) do not work. Even when I add in target:_blank, when I click the link not even a new window opens.

Please help, I am so lost and confused!

I tried this in both Brackets and Visual Studio Code. Doesn't work in either.

I created an entirely new, fresh project, and apart from the basic tags needed, the only substance I put in the body was the links... but still, not working that way either.

Inbetween these links working perfectly, and to them suddenly becoming nonresponsive, I didn't mess with any settings. Even tried disabling extensions, but that didn't do anything either.

```
 <a href="file:aPicture.jpg"> clicky</a>

>    <a href="reddit.com">click</a>
```

When I try to run either the file or www link in Visual Studio Code, I get the error of:

> < : The term '<' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>
> At line:1 char:2

```
  <a href="reddit.com">click</a>
```

> ~
>
> CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (<:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

When I try to click the file link, I get the same sort of error as well.

Comment: I think you need to add some clarity to what you are using to view/run the file that contains this markup. While it might not be great practice to have a `>` without encoding it via `&gt;`, there is still nothing wrong with this markup in terms of HTML, plus you are describing errors that come from a compiler or server-side engine, which HTML is not responsible for.

Comment: I use chrome, Brackets, and Visual Studio Code if that's what you're asking? And I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by "it might not be great practice to have a > without encoding it via &gt;"

Comment: In the first block of code provided, you have a `>` at the beginning of the second line. Ideally you would want to HTML encode that (written as `&gt;`) to avoid ambiguity in the rendering of the html. That said, you have provided what you are using to edit the code, but that is not the run-time environment. An editor is not going to give you compiler errors, as you've indicated. Is the filename you are editing just "myfile.html" or is it something ending in something else? ie: `.cshtml` or `.aspx` perhaps?